# Align image representing horizontal content border between two elements representing navigation elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally align three elements; *navigation back button*, *horizontal content border* and *navigation next button*.

```
<div class="form-navigation">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="form-back">back</a>
  <span class="form-bottom-border-wrapper">
    <img class="form-bottom-border" src="http://www.afn.org/~afn21533/icons/redthick.gif" alt="">
  </span>
 <a href="javascript:;" class="form-continue">continue</a>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qd6uens0/1/

The problem is, border has to be responsive. So it has to adapt to the space left between navigation buttons and all three elements have to stay in the same line.

My border has only 1 pixel height, unlike the one in the jsfiddle example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **CSS table** and [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.form-navigation {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-bottom-border-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.form-bottom-border-wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.form-back, .form-continue {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-navigation">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="form-back">back</a>
  <span class="form-bottom-border-wrapper"></span>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="form-continue">continue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need support for IE9 and border has to be vertically center aligned relative to navigation element height.

Comment: Does it has to be border or can you use pseudo element?

Comment: I can use pseudo element.